# generate data by linking to a food database

Tags: database

This might be a stupid question but here goes..

I have a section in my website to keep track of dietary intake. The user must select a food and the amount consumed. An algorithm should then generate the amount of calories in that food. My question is am I going to have to create my own database (which will take ages and I really don't have the time before my deadline) or is there anyway I can link my website to the food database of another website? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use free or commercial API to get the required details, below are few options

- [Nutritionix](http://www.nutritionix.com/api) has both free and commercial option
- [MyfitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/api)
- [FatSecret](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/) Api
- [Foodessential](http://developer.foodessentials.com/api) [Demo](http://foodessentials.mobi/pages/main.jsp)
- [c50 Food](https://manual.cs50.net/api/food/) api

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! I will try one of these now. I haven't hosted my website just yet as I am still developing it. Do I have to put it online before I can connect to one of the above?

Comment: you can use those API from your development environment, all you need to have is API key and Internet connection. You will get sample code available on their respective website.